# Using jQuery style multiple divs based on multiple inputs

Tags: jquery, sorting, radio-button

I have 4 separate radio select forms, and a grid of divs containing information that needs to be sorted based on the selected radio button, also by combinations of them.

for example

```
<form>
<input type="radio" name="colour" value="Blue" class="colourhook trigger">Blue<br>
<input type="radio" name="colour" value="Red" class="colourhook trigger">Red
</form>

<form>
<input type="radio" name="fruit" value="Apple" class="fruithook trigger">Apple<br>
<input type="radio" name="fruit" value="Orange" class="fruithook trigger">Orange
</form>

<form>
<input type="radio" name="size" value="Big" class="sizehook trigger">Big<br>
<input type="radio" name="size" value="Small" class="sizehook trigger">Small
</form>
```

and divs containing divs that have matching text within them

```
<div class="infobox">
    <div class="colourhook content">Blue</div>
    <div class="fruithook content">Apple</div>
    <div class="sizehook content">Small</div>
    <div class="vehiclehook content">Car</div>
</div>
 <div class="infobox">
    <div class="colourhook content">Red</div>
    <div class="fruithook content">Apple</div>
    <div class="sizehook content">Small</div>
    <div class="vehiclehook content">Bike</div>
</div>
<div class="infobox">
    <div class="colourhook content">Green</div>
    <div class="fruithook content">Orange</div>
    <div class="sizehook content">Medium</div>
    <div class="vehiclehook content">Boat</div>
</div>
```

so if "blue" is clicked only the "infobox" that contains the word "blue" within the class "colourhook" will have say a yellow background applied.

The tricky part comes when I need to have "blue" checked + "Apple" to style the info box that contains both "blue" and "apple", but not say the info box that contains "blue" and "banana"

I have a fiidle set up but I have removed my previous attempts at the query as i couldn't get it to work and need to start with a fresh approach, any help would be greatly appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/bloodygeese/k3965fr5/

Comment: put your last attempt back in please.

Comment: sorry I've deleted it as I was nowhere near!

Comment: Give a unique id attribute to each infobox div, that will greatly simplify the jquery code.

Comment: I can't as they will be created and displayed dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listen the click event for all the radio buttons and create an array of values of all selected checkboxes.

Then, loop around all the infobox containers to look for the texts in the array.

Finally, count all the match and compare it to the total number of texts in the array. If the count is equal to the total, then add the "selected" class to that infobox.

this is the full jQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("input:radio").click(function(){  
        // initialize/clear array
        text_array = [];
        // initialize/clear counter
        counter = 0;
        // get all the checked radio buttons's value and add it to the text array
        $( "input:radio:checked" ).each(function(){
                text_array[counter] = $(this).val();
                counter++;
        });
        // loop around on all the infobox
        $(".infobox").each(function(){
            var target = $(this);            
            matched = 0;
            //initialize/clear flag
            flag = [];
            // check all the child divs of the infobox for a match
            for(var i=0; i < text_array.length; i++){
               // loop through all the text in the text array to look for a match
               if ($(this).children(".content").text().match(text_array[i])) {
                    // if theres a match,set the flag for this text index to true
                    flag[i] = true;
                }
               else{
                    // there is no match, so set the flag for this text index to false
                    flag[i] = false;
               }                            
            }
            // count all flags that are true
            for(var k=0; k < flag.length; k++){
                if(flag[k] == true){
                    matched = matched + 1;                    
                }
                else{
                    matched = 0;
                }
            }
            // if the flags,that are true,is equal to the total number of flags
            // it means all the text in the array matched for this infobox
            if(matched == flag.length){
               // so add the highlight class
                target.addClass("selected");
            }
            else{
                target.removeClass("selected");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

with this CSS, to highlight the infobox that match all the radio buttons:

```
.selected{
    background: yellow !important;
}
```

**[JSfiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/k3965fr5/1/)**